# Add a custom class to a pipeline using a .config and patch attribute

Tags: asp.net, configuration, sitecore

I want this line

```
<processor type="Estate.Packages.ModificationDate.SetModificationDate, Estate.Packages" />
```

beneath

`<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel" />`

in the web.config.
I tried to do this by adding a .config file in the app_config/include folder for the website.

```
<configuration http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
        <httpRequestBegin>
            <processor x:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Sitecore.Packages.ModificationDate.SetModificationDate, Sitecore.Packages" />
        </httpRequestBegin>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

However, this ain't working. If I add the line in the web.config beneath the ExecuteRequest pipeline everything is working correctly. When I use the .config file nothing happens. (No error message either)
Anybody got a clue of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look at the Show Config tool (browse to http://yoursite/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx). It shows the final merged Sitecore configuration including all the pluggable configs out there. At least, it will give you a clue whether your injection is in the right place and in the right format. Later on you can play with the value of `x:after` attribute to find out what's wrong there.

From what I see, you mention you'd like to place your processor under `ExecuteRequest`, but your code references `ItemResolver` instead...

Comment: You are right about my copy paste fault :). I have already solved this issue now using the show config tool. Thanks!